# prove that $[0;36]$ is the range of $f(x) = 3 \sqrt{144 - x^2}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I need to prove that $[0;46]$ is the range of $f(x) = 3 \sqrt{144 - x^2}$.

At first I found that the domain of this function is $x\in [-12;12]$. So to prove that the set $[0;46]$ = $f([-12;12])$ (the image of x) I proceed to the following.

Prove that $f([-12;12]) \subset [0;46]$ => For every $x \in D = [-12;12]$, $f(x) = [0;46]$

So I wrote $-12 \leqslant x \leqslant 12$ and continued modifing $x$ in order to get the form $3 \sqrt{144 - x^2}$

**Problem** Now i'm unsure what to write next, $-144 \leqslant x^2 \leqslant 144$ or $0 \leqslant x^2 \leqslant 144$? I found the second one in my notes.

My aim is  to continue step by step writing the same for  $x^2, 144 - x^2, \sqrt{144 - x^2}$ and so on so I can finally get the form $3 \sqrt{144 - x^2}$. *I'm particularly interested in proving by this approach*.

Comment: $x^2 \ge 0$ as all squares (positive or negative $x$) must be nonnegative.

Comment: I thought about that but on the other hand I can plug in -144 as well because it is a valid element for the domain of $x^2$.

Comment: Domain: Yes. Image: No.

Comment: Don't follow rules.  Think.  $m^2 \ge 0$ always and $m^2 <0 $ is never possible.  $0 \le x^2$ is always true.  Also because $-144 < 0$ then $-144 \le x^2$ is always true (as is $-57935784\le x^2$ is always true) but not useful.    The main point is $0$ is an absolute minimum value that $x^2$ can be and it *can* be that. And $144$ is the absolute maximum value $x^2$ can be and it can be that. And $x^2 can be any value in between.  So $0\le x^2 \le 144$ is the most accurate and complete statement you can make.

Comment: "I thought about that but on the other hand I can plug in -144 as well because it is a valid element for the domain of x2"  You can plug in $-875435$ because $-875435< 0 \le x^2$ so $-875435 \le x^2$.  Just because something is true doesn't mean it is particularly useful..... And $-144$ is *not* valid element of the *DOMAIN*.  $-12$ is a valid element of the domain.  And $(-12)^2 \ne -144$.  $(-12)^2 =144$.... You may be assuming if the $a < x < c$ then $a^2 < x^2 < c^2$ but that *ISNT* true when $a$ is negative.

Comment: @fleablood you answered my question, thanks!

Comment: The more I think about it, I think your issue is that you are thinking if $-12 \le x \le 12$ then $(-12)^2 \le x^2 \le 144$ so $144 \le x^2 \le 144$. And you realize that makes no sense so you figure it's the negative sign that's throwing a monkey wrench (and you are right, that is the culprit) so you put the negative sign in front.  But $-a < x$ doesnt mean $(-a)^2 < x$ in fact if $-a <x \le 0$ then $x^2 < (-a)^2$.   If you have a case that $a\le x\le b$ where $a<0<b$ then what you do is $a \le x\le 0$ OR $0\le x\le b$ so $0\le x^2\le a^2$ OR $0\le x^2\le b^2$ so $0\le x^2 \le \max(a^2,b^2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its rather very easy to sketch the graph using derivatives, thereby finding the extrema:
[image: heheboi]

---

### Following OP's approach:

$$-12 \leqslant x \leqslant 12$$
$$\implies 0 \leqslant x^2 \leqslant 144 $$ Note that $x^2$ is always non-negative

Multiply by $-1$, thereby reversing the inequality
$$\implies 0 \geqslant -x^2 \geqslant -144$$

Add $144$

$$\implies 144 \geqslant 144-x^2 \geqslant 0$$

Take square root

$$\implies 12 \geqslant \sqrt{144-x^2} \geqslant 0$$

Multiply by $3$

$$\implies 36 \geqslant 3\sqrt{144-x^2} \geqslant 0$$

Comment: what I see Is that the value for $x^2$ is still from $-144$ to $144$

Comment: @HaykKhachatryan $(-12)^2 \ne -144$. $x^2 \in [0,144]$

Comment: thank you for your answer

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you understood :)

Answer (score 0):

Domain of $f(x)=3\sqrt{144-x^2}$ is $x \in [-12,12]$ in this domain $min(f(x))=f(\pm 12)=0$
and $max(f(x))=f(0)=36$. Hence, the range of $f(x)$ is $[0,36].$

Comment: sorry, I wrote the range for $3 \sqrt{144-x^2} + 10$, I'll edit the question now. What I'm more interested in is in proving your statement by getting $x$ to the form $3 \sqrt{144-x^2}$. More specifically the transition part from $x$ to $x^2$

Answer (score 0):

If we consider the graph of y=f(x), we can rearrange to get the ellipse $$\frac{x^2}{12^2}+\frac{y^2}{36^2}=1.$$ The function itself is only the top half since we only have the positive square root. In this form, the ellipse has center $(0,0)$, minor axis of 12 in the x-direction, and major axis of 36 in the y-direction. The domain is thus $[-12,12]$ and the range $[0,36]$.